# Debugging in VSC is not changing the environment and fails with "no module named"

Tags: visual-studio-code, miniconda

Initially, I pulled a repo and was able to run the debugger.  I set up an environment using conda (to run Python 2.7) and used pip to install the dependencies.

I then wanted to test something else, elected to put the first project into a workspace.  Now, when I try to run the project:
1) I see that the environment switches back to the (base), even though I have chosen the conda env/python
2) the modules within the project are no longer found

To illustrate, here's my starting point:
[image: starting point]

If I press F5, to run in debug mode, then it

1. Does not change the environment, even though I'm pointing to the conda env27
2. If I activate env27, it still doesn't work
   [image]

And if I try this in a Ubuntu terminal window, where I've activated the conda env27, it works
[image]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've tried running this just from the environment and get the same error.  The modules it is trying to import are in the same directory as __main__.py (the module doing the import).  So, the project is in the directory: edx-xapi-bridge (where the launch.json is) and it holds a directory called xapi_bridge.  When I invoke: `python xapi_bridge` in edx-xapi-bridge directory, it too comes back with the same error, that it cannot find xapi_bridge.

Comment: While I had the same problem from the UNIX prompt, I got this to work once I renamed the .pyc files.  In my debugging earlier, I had renamed these to *.oldpyc hoping to force a recompile. I noted now that such didn't occur.

I renamed them back to *.pyc and this issue went away; but not in the VSC env.